# Magento 1.9 blank checkout and other issues

Tags: magento, checkout

Hu guys I'm new one here and nice to find this website. I have  issue, but i dont have any fatal error so please can someone help :( , beside this problem i have more one, when i test and buy one product ,other 5 customers get same invoice automaticaly that were bought any product in past .

Can anyone help ?

Website is  http://www.hemanitrading.co.uk  and problem is on

http://www.hemanitrading.co.uk/checkout/onepage/ , it is blank, so desperately need help, if it can help i have other issues too like invalid block element when i go to cache, i refresh cache and all is good after 1 min again invalid block element and last thing is very strange. Website is live, when i go and test one product i pay for that and after that 5 people that already bought any item are getting email with my invoice :(

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: can you provide us more info about this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

If header/footer exists it means that script worked from start till end, but might be with some errors. Generally you should first of all try to look for all remove directives in your layout xml files(grep helps). It might be that the content area is simply removed by some xml.

In case XML way thing didn't worked, the things are getting tougher. You should check every template file which should be rendered in the content. it might be that content is somehow commented out.

The other thing to consider is, as far as I remember, the content block should have type list or output="toHtml" so it would be rendered automatically.

At the moment that's all what I might think off. Oh ya! And check that checkout module is enabled and it's output also enabled!

To check if module enabled you should open the **Mage_Checkout.xml** or **Mage_Cart.xml** and check if the both enabled at all.

After that in admin panel there is such page as Disable Modules Output where the output of the cart module might be disabled.

**Very important note!**
login to admin and go to  system ->  config -> advance and search for Mage_Checkout and check its enable or not. if not then enable it.

Make sure you disable all custom modules and not simply disable their output. Because in latter case you will have module working, simply with no output.

Comment: Thank you for all your help regarding checkout problem was custom.css, i never saw display:none; or visibility:hidden; but when i disable custom.css i have all now, thanks again ! 
Reuf